# How to work composer?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

For `symfony` can I use this link to composer:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ 2.3.0
```

but how the composer knows what server to use?

Is project symfony on main server composer?

How can I add own project to composer server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses `http://packagist.org/` as repository by default.

If you have open source packages you want to use you should probably put them on Github and register with packagist.

If not, you will have to create private repository using Satis: http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

Additionally you can also keep local repositories on your filesystem. In composer.json:

```
"repositories": 
[
    {
        "type":"vcs",
        "url":"/some/fs/location/repo"
    }
]
```

Comment: I think not yet, but I'm not sure, you'll have to check it out yourself :)

Comment: It works with everything that is reachable from your machine and a supported repository (git, svn, hg, ...). And the "satis" step actually is oversized, adding the repo is the first thing and should work. Adding something with "satis" is needed when you build some internal infrastructure for more projects.